# Is it worth to check the attribute value before modifying it?

Tags: java, ldap, ldap-query

Is a ldapsearch operation lighter than a ldapmodify?

Considering a single value attribute representing the current date (20210615), is it worth to check if the attribute already has the value or is it better to just do the ldapmodify?

Comment: No. Just send the update. Otherwise you are doubling the number of round-trips to the server except in the cases where the attribute already has the required value.

Answer (score -1):

Best to read-before-write.

Usually if you write the value and it is the same value you will get an error or and maybe an exception.

It is also a lot less overhead, on LDAP Server to read than to write.